# Why is the word Leviim written with only one yud: 'לויים' או 'לוים'

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, words, levites-leviyim

Do Chazal explain the inyan of the Tanach writing Levi חסר Chosser the yud that seems should be there grammatically? Does the double yud signify the rectification of the Leviim?